# I want "tokenData" equal "deviceToken" from "token"

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdata

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken]); 

    //display: 
    //<682e6887 ad7c7268 38861e90 6f4b9ba7 ced1299e abf3084b ca2ca75a 11111111>


    NSString *token = @"<682e6887 ad7c7268 38861e90 6f4b9ba7 ced1299e abf3084b ca2ca75a 11111111>";
    NSData *tokenData = [token dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tokenData]); 

    //display:
    //3c36383265363838372061643763373236382033383836316539302036663462396261372063656431323939652061626633303834622063613263613735612031313131313131313e
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand what you are saying. But you are using `NSData` and `NSString` wrongly.

```
NSString *token=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:deviceToken encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *deviceToken = [token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Use the above two functions to convert `NSString` to `NSData` and viceversa.

Comment: I create "NSData *deviceToken", but NSLog display is not equal  "(NSData *)deviceToken" Why?

Comment: i want create data touch const string, example "<682e6887 ad7c7268 38861e90 6f4b9ba7 ced1299e abf3084b ca2ca75a 11111111>"

Comment: the value equal (NSData *)deviceToken

Comment: NSString *token = @"<682e6887 ad7c7268 38861e90 6f4b9ba7 ced1299e abf3084b ca2ca75a 11111111>";
NSData *tokenData = [token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", [tokenData description]); //display "<3c36383265363838372061643763373236382033383836316539302036663462396261372063656431323939652061626633303834622063613263613735612031313131313131313e>" why?